# How to boot to single user mode in nixos

Tags: nixos

On a nixos installation how does one boot into single user mode?

On a typical linux installation one would set `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh` on the bootloader. But nixos being nixos, it has a path that looks like `init=/nix/store/[LONG-HASH]-nixos-system-nixos-18.09.228.80754f5cfd6/init`

What is the correct path to `/bin/sh`? Or is there a better way to boot to single user mode on nixos for the purpose of resetting the root password?

Comment: [Single-user mode split into 2 modes about two decades ago](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html) and  that is not actually how one invokes either one.

Comment: Take a look at this page in the NixOS manual. Note, you can type `e` with systemd-boot to edit the kernel command line: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#sec-boot-problems

Answer (score 2):

In a GRUB 2 menu you can press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the startup details. Add the word [`single` or `rescue`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231033033/https://jdebp.eu/FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html) to the line starting with `linux`, then press F10 to start in single-user or rescue mode, respectively.

You'll then need to `systemctl start network-online.target` to enable networking.